# $T7?? does not have a member 'Generator' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable named

```
var items : ItemClass
```

I initialized it like this

```
init(){
    items = ItemClass()
}
```

ItemClass is like this

```
class ItemClass{
    var property : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?

    init(){
        self.property = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to run a loop on self.items.property?.keys like below, I get an error as mentioned above in the topic.

```
for k in self.items.property?.keys
```

How can I run a loop correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property` is an optional, and as such it can potentially be nil. You can't use optional chaining in that context. So you have to either use forced unwrapping:

```
for k in items.property!.keys {

}
```

or make it safer with optional binding:

```
if let property = items.property {
    for k in property.keys {

    }
}
```